# What prior distribution could one choose to model the number of survey comments?

Tags: prior

This question has been inspired by the recent release of the results of a company survey to its employees.

There were 12,000 respondents and 16,000 comments. This means that, necessarily, more than one comment per respondent was allowed. I cannot recall if there was an upper limit of comments per respondent, but I do recall that it was possible to submit the answers to the survey without leaving one.
However, since the ratio between comments and respondents is 1.25, I am assuming that no respondent wrote more than 2 comments. Therefore, as a working assumption, I will restrict my focus on the set {0,1,2}.

Now, I'd like to obtain a plausible distribution for how many respondents left 0 comments, how many left one and how many left two.

Since there are 3 variables and only two equations, the problem is undefined and it cannot be solved as a system of equation:

```
x + y + z = 12,000 
0*x + 1*y +2*z = 16,000
```

Therefore, I was wondering if it was possible in practice to assume a distribution, on the basis of either theoretical or empirical reasons.

Comment: Sure you can assume a distribution.  Just bear in mind that what you get out of your analysis depends on what you put into it, so you're basically just making up the answer, albeit in a disguised form.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to apply the Bayes rule, I would not consider my prior using the observation (16000 and 12000), because this is not how Bayes rule can help you. Indeed, if you could solve x, y, z with observation result, that prior will not add any new information to your posterior.

Your prior and dataset would better be from 2 different sources. For example, you only studied 12000 because of limited resources but your result should instead influence 10,000,000 people. Although 2000, 8000, 2000 people left 0, 1, 2 comments respectively in your survey, how do you think those 10,000,000 people would respond? Perhaps I will dig out history survey over the last 3 years and get that estimate.

Comment: If you know where the find survey history stats that would be very helpful :)

Comment: Sorry I do not know. I know this does not solve your problem, but if I were you, I would start by thinking about what population would I apply this model to, is there any substanial difference between such population and your sample, any bias between them? Would it be "different country?", "different age group?", or something else. If I identify any one of them, I would construct my Prior based on that. I cannot provide you any data, only words that I think is important.